# Should I make a validation for user's Key Pairs generated by RSA package that the key pairs is unique(other users doesn't have the same key pairs)?

Tags: validation, security, go, cryptography, rsa

I recently working with digital signature and want to figure out **how to make each user that registered having their own key pairs for encode and decode process**. I building this kind of system using **Go**, and I use **crypto/rsa package** from Go. I already read some articles about how to make a secure digital signature and finding many kind of things. Then, I try to build the first thing for secure the process that is asymmetric encryption.

Then, the first problem that I facing is I ask myself a question **"Should I create a validation that no other user has the key pairs generated by the RSA package?"** so that will ensure each user can not pretend as other user by accident or on purpose because they have same key pairs(even if the chance is really small).

Please give me some insight about this kind of situation. If my question is not clear enough feel free to ask or complaint, I really having a hard time thinking about any security aspect for my user and system.

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "encoding/pem"
    ...
)
...
func createKeyPairs(userRegistered *User) (err error) {
    keyPairs, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 4096)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // SHOULD I ADD SOME VALIDATION FOR THE KEYPAIRS GENERATED BY CRYPTO RSA AND RAND PACKAGE HERE

    caPrivateKeyPEMFile, err := os.Create(userRequestingCA.ID + "PrivateKey.pem")
    pem.Encode(caPrivateKeyPEMFile, &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(keyPairs),
    })

    caPublicKeyPEMFile, err := os.Create(userRequestingCA.ID + "PublicKey.pem")
    pem.Encode(caPublicKeyPEMFile, &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(&keyPairs.PublicKey),
    })
}
```

Comment: i would not trust an app that records my private key on my behalf. just saying.

Comment: The answer by Marc below explains why this isn't a good idea. I also don't see how this prevents the most obvious way users could masquerade as each other, by sharing account credentials. Finally, even if you did this I could probably defeat your checking with a little number theory trickery, and I'm certainly not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you shouldn't.**

Mainly because strict **private key comparison is not sufficient**, you would need to make sure the two primes in the modulus are different.

The second reason is that **it would be mostly pointless**: the likelihood of choosing the same prime numbers is incredibly low, you would just be wasting your time.

Given a 4096 bit RSA key, you're looking for two 2048 bit prime numbers. The chances of collision for those are astronomically small.

One case where it *might* be useful would be if you had terrible entropy on your machine. But then you probably have other problems as well, and that's probably a separate question.

For more details on why the modulus primes are important (as opposed to the raw key contents), and the details on calculating the likelihood of prime collisions, please see [this security.se question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70693/what-are-the-odds-of-an-rsa-private-key-collision).

A third reason is that **it would require you to keep the parameters of all users' private keys**. You definitely shouldn't, and you probably shouldn't be generating key pairs on their behalf in the first place.